# Why do I often get electric shocks from escalators and how to avoid this?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, everyday-life

When I wear at least one cotton clothe and using escalators in different buildings containing escalators,
I often get electrical currents in first touch of the relevant escalator,
but right afterwards I can keep using the escalator until reaching the upper floor -- usually without feeling any further electrical currents.

This problem happened to me especially in winters when I was more more heavily clothed, but it definitely happened to me in all other seasons of the year;
It happened to me both in Western Asia and Europe where a 4 season year is available and in South East Asia where a 3 season year is available (no Fall season as generally all tropic trees are evergreen).

**Why do I often get electric currents from escalators and how to avoid this?**

If I need to stop wearing cotton based clothes, than I might just have to keep suffering from this but if I don't, maybe there is some accessory I can wear to stop getting these currents?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it of not a question of physics

Comment: @KyleKanos hello, voting for closing is a very easy thing to do; what about suggesting where to migrate?

Comment: Well I basically only frequent this site, so I have no idea. At one point, there was a life hacks SE site, but not sure if it exists still

Comment: @KyleKanos no sarcasm - I would reject an offer to migrate the question there; I would might suggest to mods to migrate it to Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Well considering your question is about how to avoid getting electric shock, it actually fits perfectly on what I understand that site to be. From what I understand EE site to be about, it would also not be a fit there

Comment: I assume an electricity engineer might be able to suggest a advice how to avoid this or an accessory to prevent this - I might be embarrassingly wrong about the second assumption and suggesting it only because I think LifeHacks community has enough rude people for me so much that I actually deleted my there after deleting my only question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your experience is common; here is the explanation.

Small amounts of electric charge can be moved about by friction between dissimilar, nonconducting materials (amber, glass, cotton cloth, floor carpets, shoe rubber, cat fur, etc.). If the charged surfaces are in humid air, they become sufficiently conductive to bleed those charges away before they get the chance to accumulate in sufficient amounts to produce an electric shock.

This means that in *dry conditions* as prevail in winter months, especially in air-conditioned buildings, those static electric buildups persist, and if your shoe soles and the floor surface are the right combination to segregate charge, your body will build up a goodly charge all over the outside of your skin and clothing which then sparks to the first (doorknob, escalator grip, elevator button, door frame) you touch after scuffing your feet on the carpet as you walk about.

Different shoes produce different results, which means that your winter footwear may be particularly good at scuffing up some static electricity, which would also add to the seasonal effect.

The easiest way to avoid getting finger shocks is to touch the object briefly with your elbow before touching it with your finger. Your elbow skin has fewer nerve endings in it than your fingertip does and the shock will be a lot less noticeable.

As you can see, there's a lot of interesting physics at work here!